# Computer Monitor Display Distortion

Tags: windows-7

Recently my PC has begun to experience some issues with the display. My PC is about 6 years old. I updated the Nvidia driver, I used AVG and Windows Security Essentials to remove Malware and a Trojan virus, I uninstalled most of my programs and cleaned up the registry a bit.

At some point the display seemed to fix itself (or this may have been after I used the anti malware software Zemana). Today I was attempting t reinstall Wondershare Filmora because I couldn't uninstall the trace files as the unin000.dat file was missing. I used Advanced Uninstaller to remove all trace files and then reinstalled Filmora.

As soon as I ran Filmora the display turned into the fuzzy, pixelated mess you see in the included image.

I hope someone knows what this is and how to fix it. At this staged I'm thinking I need a new computer. :/

[image: Here's a screenshot of my PC so you can see what the issue looks like.]

Comment: Your screenshot looks fine to me. Please clarify your issue.

Comment: @DavidPosthill I have edited the post but it needs to be reviewed. I have taken the screenshot down because the distortion doesn't show up. I don't know why.

Comment: If you can't see it on the screenshot, chances are it's your physical display. I'm not sure how that would relate to the software.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a hardware issue. Quite possibly a graphics card issue.
Since the screenshot shows up fine here, but not on your end.
Could also be the monitor, try connecting to a different monitor and see if the problem is still there. If so then my bet is on your GC.